# Relatively recent history of bloodbath

Tags: word-usage, etymology

[Bloodbath](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bloodbath) is a very common term used both literally and more often figuratively. Given its possible derivation from the images suggested by  wars and battles, I was surprised to see that its origin is relatively recent.

There is no entry for bloodbath in Etymonline and both  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bloodbath)  and  [Random House Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bloodbath) date its origin around 1860s

> - Coined in 1867. Compound of blood +‎ bath, the latter used referring to a metaphorical deluge.

The following book from 1851 appears to suggest that the term was probably a translation from the  term "Blutbud":

[The Life of John Sterling](https://books.google.it/books?id=VPBldh4symIC&pg=RA1-PA191&dq=%22bloodbath%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX4bmb9f_YAhWFOBQKHbISCbQQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22bloodbath%22&f=false) by Thomas Carlyle:

> - He made a ' Stockholm Blutbad' still famed in History (kind of open, ordered or permitted, Massacre of eighty or a hundred of his chief enemies there), 'Bloodbath,' so they name it; in Stockholm, where indeed he was lawful King, and not without unlawful enemies, had a bloodbath been the way to deal with them.

But according to  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bloodbath) the year in which the term was first used was 1814.

Questions:

Where does "bloodbath come from? Was it coined in English or was it imported and translated from abroad? What year does its first usages really date from?

Comment: The Stockholm Bloodbath was exactly the term that popped into my mind when I saw that 1860 date: I immediately thought “But that’s centuries after the Stockholm one!”. Note also that the _Blutbad_ mentioned in the Carlyle book is **German**, not Swedish. That part appears to be a translation of German text. The Swedish (and Danish) word is _blodbad_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The earliest use of 'bloodbath' I could find was a [2 March 1795 hyphenated use, referring to the French Revolution, in the *Caledonia Mercury*](https://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000045/17950302/007/0003) (Midlothian, Scotland; paywalled):

> *Legendre* — ".... Never shall the spirit of Terror and the reign of Blood be revived. Go take the *blood-bath* with cannibals. The National Convention of France has decided that you shall cut throats no more...."
>
> [image: blood-bath 1795]

An apparent earlier use in [a 1752 edition of Shakespeare's "The Life and Death of King John"](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433074950423;view=1up;seq=376) (Act II, "Blood bath bought blood, and blows have answer'd blows; // Strength match'd with strength, and power confronted power.") is an editorial or printer's error.

The compound, as suggested by the *OED*, formed within English, rather than being adopted from comparable Dutch, German, Swedish or Danish compounds. Those similar compounds, although characterizable with more nuanced meaning ("a massacre", "a battle"), had in 1795 been extant since at least the 15th century. As a matter of speculation, however, knowledge of those compounds may have sponsored the use by Legendre (a butcher from Paris) at the French National Convention on 15 February 1795.

The earliest attestation shown by [*OED*](http://oed.com/), is found in [the 1814 publication of *Illustrations of Northern Antiquities, from the Earlier Teutonic and Scandinavian Romances*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433000185979;view=1up;seq=11), wherein [the Scottish dialect 'bluid-bath' is glossed with English as 'blood-bath'](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433000185979;view=1up;seq=534) and both ('bluid-bath' and 'blood-bath') are noted to be translations from Danish for "a battle":

> Bluid-bath, *blood-bath*; a Danish denomination for *a battle*.

The appearance in the [R. Jamieson translation of "Stark Tiderich and Olger Danske"](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433000185979;view=1up;seq=290) is only one of the three appearances in *Northern Antiquities*. Other appearances include the gloss already mentioned and [another from the Danish romantic ballad "Oluf Pant"](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nyp.33433000185979;view=1up;seq=414) (from the Danish *Kæmpe Viser*, also translated by R. Jamieson; emphasis mine):

> I' the hen-bauks up Oluf Pant he crap;
>    There he was nagate fain;
>   The Prior took tent whareas he sat,
>    And in *blood-bath* laid him then.

The next use of 'blood-bath' I could find was in [Thomas Carlyle's 1832 essay, "Boswell's Life of Johnson"](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=osu.32435024893414;view=1up;seq=480), and again refers to the (then historical) French Revolution:

> The strongest man can but retard the current partially and for a short hour. Yet even in such shortest retardation may not an inestimable value lie? If England has escaped the *blood-bath* of a French Revolution; and may yet, in virtue of this delay and of the experience it has given, work out her deliverance calmly into a new Era, let Samuel Johnson, beyond all contemporary or succeeding men, have the praise for it.

Comment: There's a tiny typo, you forgot the "d" in Scotland. Any reason why the Scots would place *blood-bath* in italics?

Comment: @Mari-LouA, thanks. Just a guess from context: it seems to be italics for emphasis put on the word by the speaker. After that bit by Legendre, this shows up: "(A great number of members--*No, never, never!*)". Earlier in the proceedings, similar interjections of what the multitude is (supposedly) saying and doing appear without italics.

Answer (score 7):

The Oxford English Dictionary (OED.COM) says:

> **Origin**: Formed within English, by compounding. **Etymons**: blood n., bath n.
>
> **Etymology**: < blood n. + bath n.1 Compare Dutch *bloedbad* massacre
>   (1625), German *Blutbad* bloodshed, massacre (1699 or earlier), Swedish
>   *blodbad* (1582 in senses ‘bath in blood’ and ‘massacre’), Danish
>   *blodbad* massacre (1732–5), bath in blood (1904).

With a first use in 1814 in an [English translation of a Danish work](https://books.google.com/books?id=lfshAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA267&lpg=PA267#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> 1814   R. Jamieson tr. *Stark Tiderich & Olger Danske* in *Illustr.
>   Northern Antiq.* 272   There lay the steed; here lay the man; Gude
>   friends that day did twin [= part]: They leuch [= laughed] na a' to
>   the feast that cam Whan the het bluid-bath was done.

So it seems to have been formed in English as a translation of the Danish "blodbad", but the usage had also previously been found in Swedish, German, and Dutch.

Answer (score 4):

The first citation given by the OED is from an 1814 translation:

> - **1814**   R. Jamieson tr. *Stark Tiderich & Olger Danske* in Illustr. Northern Antiq. 272 
>    There lay the steed; here lay the man; Gude friends that day did twin [= part]: They leuch [= laughed] na a' to the feast that cam Whan the het bluid-bath was done.

Answer (score 1):

In 1835 the Iranian prime minister of the Qajar king Naser-al-din Shah got assassinated in a public bath. It got translated and used in English sources as fast as possible because of his fame.

The Iranian newspapers described the crime scene with the phrase "Hammame Khun" which means "Bloodbath".